# Power spectrum incorrectly yielding negative values

Tags: numpy, scipy, signal-processing, fft, spectrum

I have a real signal in time given by:

[image]

And I am simply trying to compute its power spectrum, [which is the Fourier transform of the autocorrelation of the signal, and is also a purely real and positive quantity in this case](https://personal.egr.uri.edu/chelidz/courses/mce567/handouts/psdtheory.pdf). To do this, I simply write:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.fftpack import fft, arange, rfftfreq, rfft 
from pylab import *

lags1, c1, line1, b1 = acorr(((Y_DATA)), usevlines=False, normed=True, maxlags=3998, lw=2)
Power_spectrum = (fft(np.real(c1)))
freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(len(c1), dx)
plt.plot(freqs,Power_spectrum)
plt.xlabel('f (Hz)')
plt.xlim([-20000,20000])
plt.show()
```

But the output gives:

[image]

which has negative-valued output. Although if I simply take the absolute value of the data on the y-axis and plot it (i.e. `np.abs(Power_spectrum)`), then the output is:

[image]

which is exactly what I expect. Although why is this only fixed by taking the absolute value of my power spectrum? I checked my autocorrelation and plotted it—it seems to be working as expected and matches what others have computed.

[image]

Although what appears odd is the next step when I take the FFT. The FFT function outputs negative values which is contrary to the theory discussed in the link above and I don't quite understand why. Any thoughts on what is going wrong?

Comment: maybe its an `fft.fftshift` issue?

Comment: @PaulPanzer Do you mind expanding? For example, are you saying the FFT is not considering the time-axis of the autocorrelation correctly? In the above code, is it not simply assuming constant interval spacing between the items in `np.real(c1)` with the same indexing as c1 (i.e. element 0 is the first one, element 1 is the second, etc.)?

Comment: Well, since you seem to be saying that the sizes of the spectrum are ok but not the complex arguments; that is precisely the effect of a shift in the time domain. If your autocorrelogram is centred then that is wrong because if I'm not mistaken zero in "fft coordinates" is not in the centre but on the very left. Since this discrepancy is a common headache there is this convenience function `fftshift`.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Thank you for the clarification. So it does appear to work and give me the same answer as simply taking the absolute value when I change the x-axis to `np.fft.fftshift(freqs)` and the y-axis to `fftshift(fft(ifftshift(c1)))`. The documentation does provide some information, although I'm still a little uncertain on why exactly applying `ifftshift` and then `fftshift` fixes the problem. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The power spectrum is the FFT of the autocorrelation, but that's not an efficient way to calculate it.

The autocorrelation is probably calculated with an FFT and iFFT, anyway.

The power spectrum is *also* just the squared magnitude of the FFT coefficients.

Do that instead so that the total work will be one FFT instead of 3.

Comment: Thank you for the response and I agree that it is ultimately equivalent (it is demonstrated in the above link). Although I was wondering why my approach of taking the autocorrelation and then the FFT was not working (i.e. error in my application of the FFT itself).

Comment: You probably need to perform a circular shift of your autocorrelation data so that the 0-lag coefficient goes into index 0 before you FFT.   But taking the abs() of the FFT result does the same thing.

Comment: Perhaps this is me misunderstanding a concept, but why exactly is it necessary for the 0-lag coefficient to be index 0? Isn't the FFT essentially capturing the periodic components of the autocorrelation (or any function in general), independent of any horizontal translation?

Comment: No, the FFT captures the *entire* signal.  You know it must be so, because if you do an iFFT, you'll get the same signal back.  The "horizontal translation" of the components is captured in the phase of the coefficients

Answer (score 0):

An fft produces a complex result (real and imaginary components to represent both magnitude and phase of the spectrum). You have to take the (squared) magnitude of the complex vector to get the power spectrum.

Comment: Since the autocorrelation is symmetric, it's FFT includes only real components... if you put 0 in the right place